# Language whose intersection with a CFL is always a CFL

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

> Prove or disprove: If the language $L$ is such that for every context-free language $L_0$, the language $L \cap L_0$ is context-free, then $L$ is regular.

I haven't managed to prove this, but I'm pretty sure there is no counterexample.

Comment: [Follow up.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109653/language-whose-intersection-with-a-cfl-is-always-a-cfl-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $L = \{a^n b^n : n \geq 0\}$, and let $L_0$ be an arbitrary context-free language. Define $L_1 = L_0 \cap a^* b^*$, and note that $L_1$ is context-free and $L \cap L_0 = L \cap L_1$. Let $S = \{(i,j) : a^i b^j \in L_1\}$.

According to Parikh's theorem, the set  $S$ is semilinear. The set $D = \{(n,n) \geq 0\}$ is also semilinear (in fact, it is linear). Since the semilinear sets are closed under intersection, $S \cap D$ is also semilinear. Since $S \cap D$ is (essentially) one-dimensional, it is eventually periodic. This shows that there is a finite language $F$, a modulus $m \geq 1$ and a subset $A \subseteq \{0,\ldots,m-1\}$ such that
$$
L \cap L_1 = F \Delta \{ a^n b^n : n \bmod m \in A \},
$$
where $\Delta$ is symmetric difference. It is easy to check that $\{a^nb^n : n \bmod m \in A\}$ is context-free, and so $L \cap L_1$ is context-free.

Summarizing, we have shown that $L$ is a non-regular language which satisfies your condition.

Comment: i dont know (or allowed )to use the Parikj's theorem there is  any way you can show it without the linearity, thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t care about this sort of artificial constraint. In mathematics we can use everything we know.

Comment: If you don't know something, why not look it up? Be curious.

Comment: I wrote this once before but it must've vanished in the ether: your $L$ is context-free. So what am I missing here?

Comment: @Kai: $L$ is indeed context-free, but it is not regular, while the claim in the OP is that every context-free language fulfilling the stated conditions must be regular. So $L$ is a counterxample to that claim.

Comment: The edit I had hoped for has happened.

Comment: @Kai $L$ has to be context-free, since you can choose $L_0$ to be $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: To simplify the end of the proof, for any semilinear set $T\subseteq\mathbb{N}^2$ it is easy to show that $L=\{a^i b^j : (i,j)\in T\}$ is a context-free language by explicitly constructing a grammar. This shows that any non-regular context-free language that is contained in $a^* b^*$ can be used as a counter example.

Comment: The same result is proved in Ginsburg and Spanier, Bounded ALGOL-like languages (1964), Corollary 1 to Theorem 6.1.