# Conditions that imply closure under intersection of context-free languages

Tags: context-free, reference-request

Context-free languages are not closed under intersection.

Suppose $L_1, L_2 \in CF \setminus REG$ (i.e., $L_1,L_2$ are context-free but not regular).

> Are there well-known theorems (and/or whole papers/research topics) that try to shape the sufficient/necessary conditions for $L_1,L_2$ to make $L_1 \cap L_2$ context free?

Comment: The background of this question is that it is undecidable whether the intersection of two context-free languages is context-free.

Comment: You can probably generalize the example in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/106659/683). We can ask more generally, which context-free language are such that their intersection with a context-free language is always context-free.

Comment: A related question, [_language whose intersection with a CFL is always a CFL_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109653/91753).