# Language whose intersection with a CFL is always a CFL (2)

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106657/language-whose-intersection-with-a-cfl-is-always-a-cfl), which asks for an example of a non-regular language $L$ which satisfies the following condition, *intersection resilience*:

> If $L'$ is context-free then so is $L \cap L'$.

We know that all regular languages are intersection-resilient, and clearly every intersection-resilient language is context-free. Ginsburg and Spanier showed in 1964, in their paper [Bounded ALGOL-like languages](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1964-113-02/S0002-9947-1964-0181500-1/S0002-9947-1964-0181500-1.pdf), that every context-free subset of $x^*y^*$ is intersection-resilient (Theorem 6.1, Corollary 2).

> Which languages are intersection-resilient?

Comment: A related question is whether it is decidable whether a given context-free language is intersection-resilient. Another related question is whether the intersection of an intersection-resilient language and an context-free language is intersection-resilient. Note that the intersection of two intersection-resilient languages is intersection-resilient.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few notes (I'll try to add the proofs later).

Intersection-resilience seems closed under homomorphism.

A necessary condition for intersection-resilience is that for all homomorphisms $\varphi : \Sigma \to \Sigma \cup\ \{\epsilon \}$; $\varphi(L) \cap x^*y^*x^*$ must be a regular language (where $x$ and $y$ are any two distinct symbols of $\Sigma$).

So the result of Ginsburg and Spanier seems "tight" (if we use the same homomorphism trick).